# Problem with shadow around edges

Tags: shadows

There is a strange shadow around some edges of a model I am working with:
[image: shadows]

This shadows only visible when scene rendered with Eevee/Cycles. I am not an expert in 3D modelling, but topology seems fine:
[image: Topo]

I checked for duplicated faces and verteces, recalculated normals, tried to smooth surface in Sculpt mode, but nothing really helped.

What causes this problem and how can I fix it? Link to the .blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3n9b5vdbfah88z3/shadow_artifact.blend?dl=0

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Eevee setting, in the shadow section, try to lower "cascade size" to 256 pixels. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/shadows.html#shadows

Comment: Yep, this fixed the problem. Thanks for your help!